# Parse error building website with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, static

I recently did the blog tutorial for CakePHP, as is found here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html

I have CakePHP version 2.8.5, and WampServer with Apache 2.4.9, PHP 5.5.12 and MySQL 5.6.17, and got the blog running on localhost/.

I am now trying to upload the blog to a server online, and have used SmartFTP to upload files to the folder public_html on a free web server online, but when I visit the domain, I receive:

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/a3087838/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 221

Line 221 is:

```
 if (!empty(static::$legacy[$type])) {
```

which is part of:

```
 public static function path($type, $plugin = null) {
    if (!empty(static::$legacy[$type])) {
        $type = static::$legacy[$type];
    }
```

I have seen similar questions asked online, but the solution seems to be that PHP version 5.3 or greater is required as prior versions don't support late static binding, but my version is 5.5.12, so I shouldn't have that problem.

I tried replacing the word `static` with `self`, but the error then just reiterates itself for later lines containing `static`. I repeated this down to line 282 and it's behaviour didn't change. I could replace all other instances of `static` with `self`, but that will take a while and I expect there is a better solution that I am missing, if that is even a solution. I am inexperienced and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain your web handler is using PHP > 5.3? Sometimes if you try `php -v` in the command line and you see something like 5.5.12, that may not be the version being used for web requests, only on command line. Try sticking a `phpinfo()` somewhere and double check...

Comment: I made a phpinfo.php file with `phpinfo()` in it, and localhost/phpinfo.php gave me the info page saying vers.5.5.12. :/

Comment: Ah! I just noticed that the web server is using PHP 5.2. So I will need to change this to a more recent version?